# C# Threading function with object return

Tags: c#, multithreading

Currently I have a List string ids which holds a bunch of ids, a List object that starts empty and fills with objects, and a function returns an object getObject(string id) that gets the object given the id string. Is there a way to thread this easily instead of having to do it serially using the Threading class? It doesn't seem like there's a way for threads to return objects since they use void functions.

Comment: Use `Task` instead of `Thread`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Why?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: The old fashioned way (pre-Task/Async): Author a class that contains the state you want to manage.  Make one of the public methods of the class be your "thread function" (the right call signature, etc.).  Create an instance of the class, initialize the state to whatever you want as an initial state.  Dispatch a delegate representing `myInstance.ThreadFunc' to the thread pool.  When the thread completes, look at the state of the object.

Comment: @Stefan Why not? `Task` provide convenient abstraction whenever you use separate `Thread` or `ThreadPool`. And you can plug-in custom `TaskScheduler`, if you have special needs. And it solves result/exception passing back to task creator, exactly what OP ask. As well it provide many useful features, like continuation, etc. Unless you pursue raw performance, I do not see compelling reason not to use `Task`, if it available to you.

Comment: public static void Execute()
        {
            List<string> pipe = getPipeline();

            List<Loan> loans = new List<Loan>();

            foreach (string i in pipe)
            {
                loans.Add(GetLoan(i));
            }
        }

How would I add async tasks to that? Would I do something like loans.Add(await getLoansAsync(i))? Would that do the tasks in parellel or one at a time? How many are done at the same time?

Comment: @PetSerAl: ah, thanks!

Comment: The problem with a thread that returns a value is that *somebody* has to be around to wait until the thread is done so it can retrieve the value.  Another thread.  Which defeats the point of using a thread in the first place, the thread that waits might as well run the code that the other thread was supposed to execute.  And you don't need a separate thread anymore.  You have to "push", tell other code that a result is available.  Thread doesn't do that.  But other classes do.  Like BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted does.  Or Task.  Or a thread-safe queue that you fill with data.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var task = Task.Run<object>(() => /** your delegate returning an object **/)
```

You can then handle it using `Result`, `Wait`, or (the best, preferred wait) the `await` keyword.

```
var returnedObject = await task;
```

More on `Task`s here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `getObject(string id)` method is thread safe and is CPU intensive (i.e. it doesn't perform I/O operations), then [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) is probably best option. It does automatically all the magic of partitioning input list, distributing workload to all available CPU cores and then merging sub-results back to one resulting list.

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" });

List<Object> objects = ids
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(id => getObject(id))
    .ToList();
```

If needed, you can also configure it with `.WithDegreeOfParallelism()`, `.WithExecutionMode()` and `.WithMergeOptions()` extensions methods (but usually it works well with default options).

But if `getObject()` method is I/O bound, then using `Task` will be probably better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing two ways to do this, one the "Old-fashioned" way, one with a Task.  Both of them are in a simple demo WinForms app (just because...)

Here is the old-fashioned way (submitting work explicitly to the thread pool).  For this, I created a simple little class:

```
public class OldFashionedThread
{
    private readonly List<string> _listOfStrings = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> ListOfStrings => _listOfStrings;
    public Form1 TheForm { get; set; }

    public void DoWork(object state)
    {
        var strings = new[] {"Some", "strings", "go", "here"};
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            _listOfStrings.Add(s);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        TheForm?.Invoke(new Action(TheForm.AlertAllDone));
    }
}
```

The "AlertAllDone" just pops up a message box saying "all done"

Then, on my main form, I have:

```
   private OldFashionedThread _worker;
   private void StartThreadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       _worker = new OldFashionedThread {TheForm = this};
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_worker.DoWork);
   }

   private void AllDoneBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (_worker != null)
       {
           var result = string.Join(" ", _worker.ListOfStrings);
           MessageBox.Show(result);
       }
   }
```

I click the `StartThreadBtn` button, wait till the All Done message box happens and then click the `AllDoneBtn` button.

Using a task, I can do this (directly in the form's code):

```
   private async void AsTaskBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var strings = await GetStringsAsync();
       var result = string.Join(" ", strings);
       MessageBox.Show(result);
   }

   private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetStringsAsync()
   {
       return await Task.Run<IEnumerable<string>>(
           () => {
               var listOfStrings = new List<string>();
               var strings = new[] { "Some", "strings", "go", "here" };
               foreach (var s in strings)
               {
                   listOfStrings.Add(s);
                   Thread.Sleep(500);
               }
               return listOfStrings;
           });
   }
```

The `await` lets me just wait till the work is finished (without tying up the UI thread) and then, when it's finished, I wake up and pop up the message box.